# Italy Schengen tourist visa Funds documentation

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, proof-of-funds, tourist-visas

Why is Savings Bank Account statements not acceptable for the purpose of Tourist Schengen Visa to Italy ? The official website clearly mentions that only Current Account statements are accepted - I dont have a current account - but can show enough balance in my Savings account.

[Italy embassy in UK tourist visa site](http://it.vfsglobal.co.uk/nonimmigrant_tourist_documents.html)

What about Traveller's Cheque instead of Current Account? Or should I open a new current account now (I am applying for the Visa in next 10-15 days)?

Comment: Not having a current account (while using the banking system and living in Europe) would seem unusual. You don't have any debit card? A cheque book? Any standing order to pay bills? Any way to withdraw cash quickly from this account? If any of those can be done directly from your “savings” account, then I would say it's a current account with interests and should be perfectly fine.

Comment: I have all these things with my account - so I am guessing even though its called as Savings account - its pretty much a current account.Will find out with bank directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason might be the different types of [savings accounts available](http://www.which.co.uk/money/savings-and-investments/guides/finding-the-best-savings-account/the-different-types-of-savings-account/) for some of which access to funds may not be readily available, so if you need to get access to money you may not be able to get it from the account.

So this may be intended as a safety net but this would be a question better asked at the consulate.